# Pass optional block or closure to a function in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

What is the correct syntax to pass an optional block to a function in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one make an optional closure in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395853/how-does-one-make-an-optional-closure-in-swift)

Comment: Covers same info, but an Objective-C developer may not find that answer (as I didn't) as a result of searching for "block" rather than "closure". Closure is of course correct Swift terminology.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Although not as hard to remember as the Objective-C block syntax, it's far from obvious. The `notConnected` parameter is optional in this example:

```
    func whenConnected(block: Void -> Void, notConnected: ((Void) -> Void)?, showErrorMessage: Bool) -> Void {

        let connected = Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()

        if connected {
            block()
        } else {
            notConnected?()
        }

        if showErrorMessage {
            // your error handling //
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

I found the example of it (see link below) and modified it to use `typealias` in my project.

**Swift 3:**

```
import Foundation

typealias CompletionBlock = (NSError?) -> Void
var completionBlock: CompletionBlock?

// a function declaration w/ optional closure param and default value
func doSomething(completion: CompletionBlock? = nil) {
    // assign to the property, to call back out of this function's scope
    completionBlock = completion
    // ...
    // optional closure callback
    completionBlock?(nil)
    // ...
}

func doSomethingElse() {
    // 1. pass optional (nil) closure to a function
    doSomething()

    // 2. pass optional (non-nil) closure to a function
    doSomething(completion: { (error) -> Void in
        print("error: \(error)")
    })
}
```

Source: [Optional trailing closures in Swift](http://evgenii.com/blog/optional-trailing-closures-in-swift/)

**NOTE:** Because the `completion` is declared as an optional closure, it always **escapes**. More on that: [Optional Non-Escaping Closures](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures/)

Answer (score 1):

```
   typealias ServiceResponse = (AnyObject? , String?) -> Void

   func request(onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse){
         stuff you need to write
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details