# How to call more than one function in a function when the first function finished running?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Here is my flow in simple form. I still need to call decisionMaker() when finished  after #2 is finished running do to the time is up and take the global variable for the measurements to decisionmaker() for the case test
**

/*
TestButtonTAPPED() and calls:

```
1. recordTimer()
2. gatherInput()
 2a. selector: levelTimerCallback()
 
3. decisionMaker()
```

*/

```
// 1.
func recordTimer() {
    /* After 10 seconds, let's stop the recording process */
    let delayInSeconds = 10.0
    let delayInNanoSeconds = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.after(when: delayInNanoSeconds, execute: {
        self.soundRecorder!.stop()
        self.handBtn.isHidden = false
    })
    
}

// 2.
func gatherInput() {
    levelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self, selector: #selector(DBListener.levelTimerCallback), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
}


 func levelTimerCallback() {
    if soundRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) > -30
    {
        // Do gathering for vaiables
    }
}


// 3.
func decisionMaker() {
    // case statments here for final measurement
}
```

}

Comment: please, try to rewrite your question as it is unclear what you're asking

Comment: Perhaps provide some code for what you've tried.

Comment: Are you trying to call different functions after each other with a delay? (sry, the description is pretty unclear to me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass optional block or closure to a function in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185941/pass-optional-block-or-closure-to-a-function-in-swift)

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to say it.... :)  @gujci

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution if I get the idea right.

```
 var callbacks: [() -> ()] = []

 var levelTimerCallback = {
     //some code here...
 }

 var decisionMaker = {
     //other code here...
 }

 (1...9).forEach() { _ in
     callbacks.append(levelTimerCallback)
 }

 callbacks.append(decisionMaker)

 func timerCallback() {

     let operation = callbacks.removeFirst()
     operation()
 }

 var levelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self, selector:   #selector(timerCallback), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
```

So this would call the levelTimer 9 times and the decisionMaker at the end. Although I'm still not sure, that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let me test that, that is what I am trying to do in a nut shell. What you call the way you declare the callbacks: [() -> ()] = [] ?

Comment: [() -> ()] = [] this declares an array of functions that does not have parameters and return values. So you can add all the necessary callbacks to it.