# What kinda callback is this called?

Tags: swift, callback

I started using this type of call back in my programs but i don't know what they are actually called. I set an instance variable of my class to `var callback:()->Void` and then in my view i just add an action to a button that calls the callback. Which allows me to set its functionality in the class i am adding the view to. But what is it called? I want to be able to look up the other options i have with using this type of callback?

So im trying to look for ways i can modify the return value and see if there are any other hidden secrets related to callbacks that i dont know of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Call back function is useful when you pass data to the previous viewController or in Asynchronous function.

You can also refer following links

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

[Pass optional block or closure to a function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185941/pass-optional-block-or-closure-to-a-function-in-swift)