# how can i return value from this function?

Tags: swift

https://coinpaprika.github.io/coinpaprika-api-swift-client/index.html

```
func gettingFunction(name: String){
    Coinpaprika.API.coins().perform { (response) in
      switch response {
      case .success(let coins):

                return coins[0].id // i want return this value            

        case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        // Failure reason as error
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please look up “how to return value from asynchronous function” – this has been asked and answered many times already.

Comment: Read here about callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429090/swift-variable-declared-outside-closure-is-updated-inside-closure-but-when-acces/61429216#61429216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an async call so you can use `completion` to do this. And you can pass `Result` type in completion with values

```swift
func gettingFunction(name: String, _ completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void {
    Coinpaprika.API.coins().perform { response in
        switch response {
        case .success(let coins):

            completion(.success(coins[0].id))            

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(.failure(error))
      }

    }
}
```

---

Usage

```swift
gettingFunction(name: "asd") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let id):
        print("ID is:", id)
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error is:", error)
    }
}
```

---

If you want to use the value in another function. You should call this function in `.success` case because we have the ID value in this case.

```swift
gettingFunction(name: "asd") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let id):
        print("ID is:", id)
        anotherFunction(id: id)

    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error is:", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS MAN, but what if i want return this value to another function? for example 
function(id: gettingFunction(name: "asd"))