# Turning a firebase database value into a variable Swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase, var

I have a var declared and I can retrieve the value from Firebase Database but when I then print the var in ViewDidLoad, it is empty, I don't understand what's wrong. Thanks everyone
This is the answer I get when I print the var : this is the language

```
//
var language: String = ""

//
func getUserLanguage(completion:((String) -> Void)?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    ref.child("users").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
       let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       let languageResult = value?["language"] as? String ?? ""
       completion?(languageResult)
    }
)}

//
getUserLanguage { (languageResult) in
   self.language = languageResult
}

// I print the value in ViewDidload
print("this is the language\(self.language)")
```

Comment: How are you getting nil when you assign empty string with `value?["language"] as? String ?? ""` when unwrapping fails? And try using `[String: Any]` instead of `NSDictionary` and check whether snapshot actually returns the value.

Comment: The snapshot returns the value but only inside the function, when I call the var anywhere else than this function, it is = nil

Comment: `var language: String = ""` is not an optional. You can never get its value as `nil`. If you are calling `getUserLanguage` in `viewDidLoad` and trying to access it before the completion is called, you will get an empty string. Can you add the snapshot value in question?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what I am supposed to do, and the snapshot value is supposed to be "english"

Comment: can you pls add the printed snapshot value in your question?

Comment: I've modified the question

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete as we don't know the order of your code execution. Printing self.language in viewDidLoad would print nothing unless that var was populated before printing, right? When is `getUserLanguage` called and where are there two lines with that same name? How do you know that the read node has a child 'language'? Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update and clarify the question and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to print `languageResult` in function - maybe you don't get it inside the function and the variable is not assigned
2. Make `language` variable public

Comment: Making the var public doesn't change much. The function works and inside of it the right value is retrieved from Firebase, it is when I try to use the variable somewhere else that its value hasn't been updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the asynchronous nature of your code here. The `getUserLanguage` function will call the completion only when it gets callback from `observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)` method of firebase. It is asynchronous. You won't get the value of `language` right after you call `getUserLanguage` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    getUserLanguage { (language) in
        print(language) // --> prints the expected value
        self.language = language
    }
    print(language) // --> prints ""
}

func getUserLanguage(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    ref.child("users").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        let languageResult = value?["language"] as? String ?? ""
        print("language: ", languageResult) // --> prints the expected value

        completion(languageResult)
    })
}
```

Comment: How can I fix this then? I would like to be able to turn this value that I retrieve from Firebase with a snapshot into a variable

Comment: You can use the variable `language` but its value will be set only after the completion closure is called in `getUserLanguage`. Pls check where I have set self.`language`. If you want to do something with it inside `viewDidLoad` itself, do it after that line. You can do whatever you want with that variable after that.

Comment: Yes but for example the _print(language)_ just after _getUserLanguage_ is called in ViewDidLoad() returns empty, so I can't use the variable outside of _getUserLanguage_, why is the variable updated but only inside the function?

Comment: Pls read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245943/5443937 and try to experiment with closures/completion handlers

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read the article and tried to Implement it into my code but nothing seems to work, I don't know what to do about it anymore