# How to extract data from networking class into variable in same class so that it can be accessed from other class in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to extract data from networking class into variable in same class so that it can be accessed from other class in ios

**Code for Networking Class**

```
import Foundation

struct NetworkManager {
    func fetchData(url : String) {
        print("Neeraj here")
        let sessionURL = URL(string: url)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: sessionURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let parsedData = self.parseData(data : safeData) {
                        print("got data")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("error in data task is \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
    
    func parseData(data : Data) -> DataModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DataModel.self, from: data)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            print("error while parsing data \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here where i am getting data, i want that data to be stored somewhere or in same class so that i can access it from class i am calling this method **fetchData**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the closure to return the value out of the function. This practice is functional programming, almost using for async function.

```
func fetchData(url: String, completion: (DataModel?) -> ()) {
    ...
    if let parsedData = self.parseData(data : safeData) {
        print("got data")
        completion(parsedData)
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

And then, to use it:

```
NetworkManager().fetchData(url: "https://google.com", completion: { data in
    // handle the “data”
})
```

Comment: When i am using this i am getting an error in line ```let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: sessionURL!) { (data, response, error) in``` that "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion". What does this mean

Comment: I am missing the @escaping. You can refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245943/10267768

Comment: yes, thanks for help. I appreciate your help