# Trying to implement custom functionality to a SwiftUI button, keep getting a warning

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a custom button where I can implement my own functionality, like in the example below:

```
MSButton {
    print("hello")
}
```

Problem is, I keep getting the `Expression of type '(() -> Void)?' is unused` warning, and the functionality I add doesn't activate.

Here is the code I made in an attempt to implement this:

```
struct MSButton: View {
    
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            action // where I am getting the warning.
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing that would allow me to get my `action` to work properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67012282/5133585) answer your question? Look at how they have passed the action.

Comment: @Sweeper The implementation I'm looking for seems to be different than how the post you linked goes about solving it.

Comment: Please describe *how* exactly it is different. What is "the implementation you're looking for"?

Comment: @Sweeper I was able to figure it out. You can see my answer below to see what I was trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978078/6433023

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. My implementation is below:

```
struct MSButton: View {
    
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            self.action!() // fixed line
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

It works, although I don't understand exactly why this works, rather than the code I wrote in my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978078/6433023

Comment: It would be safer to say `self.action?()`. When you force unwrap you risk a crash. This code works because you are invoking the closure via `()` In your original code you weren't. You had the equivalent of `2` just sitting there, so the compiler tells you that you aren't doing anything with the value

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, you forgot to call it as a function. Therefore, the correct answer is `self.action?()`

I personally would recommend to set it up like this

```
struct MSButton: View {
    var action: (() -> Void) = { }
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            self.action()
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```